# JSF navigation rule doesn't work after glassfish update

Tags: java, jsf-2, glassfish-3, netbeans-7

I have navigation rules like

```
<navigation-case>
  <description>
  Global rule for going to the items page from any page  
  </description>
  <from-outcome>items</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>/items.xhtml</to-view-id>
  <redirect>
    <view-param>
      <name>page</name>
      <value>#{itemsBean.page}</value>
    </view-param>  
  </redirect>  
  </navigation-case>
```

In that rules I used variable "page" from itemsBean that is RequestScoped.

While I used Netbeans 7.0.1 and GlassFish 3.1.1 - it's worked fine. But after updating to NetBeans 7.2 and GlassFish 3.1.2.2 rules doesn't work. There are "#{itemsBean.page}" In the address string instead of it's value. Seems like expressions in rules doesn't work, but why?

P.S. I made simple project to test at home and found, that JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final work with navigation rules just like GlassFish 3.1.2.2. Maybe it's a feature?

Thanks for wasting your time.